# Sheep it wont render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, sheepit

i have a few animation projects coming up due to render in the next month or so. I downloaded Sheep It in the mean time so i can contribute to others renders as well as rack up points for myself for when i am ready to render. I set it up across 2 computers (Intel Core i5-4260U @ 1.40CHz x4 and a Intel Core i7-4750HQ @ 2.00GHz x8), and the friend who introduced me to SheepIt linked his computer up as well via the KEY. Seemed to be going fine but when he disconnected the frame render count stopped, it seems that my computers wernt rendering at all it was just piggy backing on his. Can anyone tell me what ive done wrong please. 
Ive tried connecting wirelessly as well as via an Ethernet cable and still no change.

Comment: I would contact the developers of SheepIt directly. It's unlikely many people here have experienced your specific issue regarding that 3rd party service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a third party rendering service

Answer (score 1):

I took the Mentalists advice and contacted the developers and they updated the system and it works fine now. Thanks for your replies.